# how to get n digits of a given number?

Tags: decimal-expansion

I have very large number. I have to operate first n digits from left.

Is there a command in Mathematica that will give n digits of a given number
something like   xxxxx[123456789,  5]=12345?

IntegerPart[N[number/10^n]]is generating internal errors.

Comment: Cast the number as a string, then find the substring over the desired length, finally casting back as a number again.  `ToExpression(StringPart(ToString(123456789),1;;5;;1))`

Answer (score 0):

Try `RealDigits[]`.

```
N[2000!, 50]
RealDigits[N[2000!, 50], 10]

(*  3.3162750924506332411753933805763240382811172081058*10^5735  *)
(*  {{3, 3, 1, 6, 2, 7, 5, 0, 9, 2, 4, 5, 0, 6, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 7, 5, 3, 9, 3, 3, 8, 0, 5, 7, 6, 3, 2, 4, 0, 3, 8, 2, 8, 1, 1, 1, 7, 2, 0,   8, 1, 0, 5, 8}, 5736}  *)
```

Comment: Thanks with your help I have figured out it

Comment: as  FromDigits[RealDigits[N[k/10^125, 125], 10]]

Comment: IntegerPart[N[num/10^(IntegerLength[num]-n),n] work well provided n<IntegerLength[num]